# I have a function and I need to know when it will return true and not false

Tags: javascript

I have this funtion

```
function riddle (parme) {
  if(parme !== parme) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

when will it return true (I dont know the language)

Comment: I don’t think it will ever return true. AFAIK a variable is alway equal to itself. — Unless someone adds a global property with a getter which returns a random value?

Comment: how will you do that?

Comment: @tchStud1405 its more about will someone will ever do that the answer is no.

Comment: It prints false

Comment: I was incorrect (unsurprising). Check decpk’s answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is only a single value in JS which is not equal to itself which is `NaN`. Rest in all cases, it will print `false`

To check for `NaN` equality, You should use [`isNaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN)

```js
function riddle(parme) {
  if (parme !== parme) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}

console.log(riddle(NaN));
```

Comment: Why doesn’t null work too?

Comment: @evolutionxbox I was saying about `NaN` not `null`. excuse me